# When copying file from HugginFace to GoogleColab with wget I only get a small size

Tags: google-colaboratory, huggingface-hub

I have identified my account in Google Colab by providing a token

```py
    from huggingface_hub import notebook_login
    notebook_login()
```

then I would like to copy this 6.5 Go file :

```
    !wget https://huggingface.co/stabilityai/stable-diffusion-xl-base-1.0/blob/main/sd_xl_base_1.0.safetensors
```

Unfortunately it gets only 53K

[image]

Is there a way to overcome this limitation ?

Comment: That doesn't seem to be related to colab. Open the URL and click the download button. Your browser will start the download. You can interrupt it right away and copy the download URL.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the fix I have found : Registering a token from HuggingFace to Google Colab, then use hf_hub_url function to get the right url

```
from huggingface_hub import notebook_login
notebook_login()
from huggingface_hub import hf_hub_url

myPath=  hf_hub_url(
    repo_id="stabilityai/stable-diffusion-xl-base-1.0", filename="sd_xl_base_1.0.safetensors"
)
!wget $myPath
```